# Can I make a play music command from youtube on dsharpplus?

Tags: c#, discord, chatbot

I am making a discord bot using DSharpPlus. I want to make a command which will play music directly from youtube through a link. Can somebody help me with how I can make that, giving me tips, please?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, however I don't habe enough reputation to do so.
Check out [these examples](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/Example-Bots) on GitHub. Example #4 should be exactly what you're looking for. If you encounter any problems along your way, please note the comments to your question.